# Facebook SDK for .NET System.MethodAccessException LoginBehaviorMobileInternetExplorerOnly

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, facebook-c#-sdk

I have been trying to use the process described [here](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/login/) to login to facebook from Windows Phone app through Internet Explorer

But I keep on getting System.MethodAccessException after providing permission from facebook on internet explorer.

To me, it seems that there is some problem in the following line of code -

```
RootFrame.UriMapper = new FacebookUriMapper();
```

I have added FacebookConfig.xml file to the root directory of my app with the following contents-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Extensions>
<Facebook AppId="*****MY APP ID*****" />

    <!-- 
    The following is needed only for Windows Phone Silverlight apps. Since the page to redirect after facebook authentication
    can be different than MainPage.xaml, set this field here to get redirected to the appropriate page.
    -->
    <RedirectPage Name="MainPage.xaml" />
</Extensions>
```

I have also added the following extension to the WMAppManifest.xml-

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="fb*****MY APP ID*****" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" /> <!-- Browser based authentication -->
</Extensions>
```

But it does not work.

What might I be missing?
Anyone has been successful in implementing this?? It works in Candy Crush.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It seems there is a problem in the documentation.</strike>

The documentation states that you have to add the following to your WMAppManifest.xml file-

```
<Extensions>
   <Protocol Name="fb861850377206***" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
   <Protocol Name="msft-a3c419***65b42b1841692f386c4d190" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Well, the problem in the documentation is that

```
NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s"
```

should be replaced with

```
NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri={0}"
```

%s is used in Java and maybe some other languages also. But it should be "{0}" in case of C#.

OK I guess my previous answer was wrong :/ It didn't work for me as well, only the app didn't crash.

But a change was updated to the Facebook SDK today itself and I was able to get it working as follows-

1. Download the source code from https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-winclient-sdk. I don't know if it works when installing from NuGet. I just got it working after fetching the source code.
2. Build the source code. You should now have Facebook.dll and Facebook.Client.dll in the build folder.
3. Reference these dlls in your project and follow the instructions on the project site and it should work then.